Flutter Riverpod 2.5.1 not updating StateNotifier value on read
I have a flutter app and I want to use flutter_riverpod as a global state manager. The problem is that I cant access my variable even when i use the read method. What am I doing wrong?
My Screen code:

class MySCcreenScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MySCcreenScreen({super.key});
  @override
  ConsumerState<MySCcreenScreen> createState() =>
      _MySCcreenScreenState();
}

class _MySCcreenScreenState
    extends ConsumerState<MySCcreenScreen>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
      bool disabled = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    final form = ref.watch(complimentFormProvider);
    safePrint(form);

    void handleProceed() {
      safePrint('form.id ${form.id}');
    }

    double baseScreenPadding = 20;
    double screenHeight = getScreenHeight(context);

    return Scaffold(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: baseScreenPadding),
        considerScroll: true,
        body:
          ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: screenHeight,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  MyInput(
                    handleSubmit: handleProceed,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  SubmitButton(
                    text: 'Submit',
                    disabled: disabled,
                    onPress: handleProceed,
                  ),
                ],
              ))
        );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}

MyInput code
class MyInput extends ConsumerWidget {
  final Function() handleSubmit;

  const MyInput({super.key, required this.handleSubmit});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final form = ref.watch(formProvider);

    void setId(String newValue) {
      safePrint('newValue $newValue');
      safePrint('form.id ${form.id}');
      ref
          .read(formProvider.notifier)
          .setId(newValue);
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        InputId(
          setId: setId,
          onSubmit: handleSubmit,
          keyboardAction: TextInputAction.next,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

My InputId code:
void emptyFunction() {}

class InputId extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<String> setId;
  final TextInputAction keyboardAction;
  final Function() onSubmit;

  const InputId({
    super.key,
    required this.setId,
    this.keyboardAction = TextInputAction.done,
    this.onSubmit = emptyFunction,
  });

  @override
  State<InputId> createState() => _InputIdState();
}

class _InputIdState extends State<InputId> {
  final TextEditingController inputController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    inputController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void updateId() {
    widget.setId(inputController.text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          textInputAction: widget.keyboardAction,
          onEditingComplete: widget.onSubmit,
          controller: inputController,
          enableSuggestions: false,
          autocorrect: false,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          enableInteractiveSelection: false,
          autofocus: true,
          onChanged: (value) {
            updateId();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

and my riverpod code:
class MyFormState {
  String id;
  String name;

  MyFormState(
      {this.id = '', this.name = ''});
}

class MyFormNotifier extends StateNotifier<MyFormState> {
  MyFormState _state = MyFormState();

  MyFormNotifier() : super(MyFormState());

  void setId(String id) {
    _state = MyFormState(
      id: id,
      name: _state.name,
    );
  }

  void setName(String name) {
    _state = MyFormState(
      id: _state.id,
      name: name,
    );
  }
}

final formProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<MyFormNotifier, MyFormState>(
  (ref) => MyFormNotifier(),
);


It is important to note, that I am suspicious about the tree widget:
screen
---Input
------InputId
Does this has any influence?

Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

The StateNotifier own a state variable, and I was using a private _state variable.
So my change should be like:
class MyFormNotifier extends StateNotifier<MyFormState> {
  MyFormNotifier() : super(MyFormState());

  void setId(String id) {
    state = MyFormState(
      id: id,
      name: state.name, // Aqui estamos usando o estado atual
    );
  }

  void setName(String name) {
    state = MyFormState(
      id: state.id,
      name: name,
    );
  }
}

